# Getting real time browsing url in core java

Tags: java, windows, swing, url, browser

I want to develop a java application (run in windows) that can catch the url of the browser. what ever be the browser be, the url should be print in java. I tried it by listening to http socket, it doesnt work for me. Any one have any ideas?

I tried jpcap application, socket programing (java.net package)

But when i used jpcap. The following exception came.

The program run successfully in 2010 in xp. Now i am using windows 7

```
import jpcap.JpcapCaptor;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author james
 *
 */
public class NetworkInterface {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    jpcap.NetworkInterface[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
    System.out.println(devices);

}

}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList()[Ljpcap/NetworkInterface;
    at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList(Native Method)
    at NetworkInterface.main(NetworkInterface.java:17)
```

Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and come back when you have a more specific programming-related question.

Comment: I don't think is asking for code. He just want an idea of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/) API on your java program to sniff packets. HTTP requests will have the URL on the first line.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028679/why-am-i-getting-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-below-program) to solve the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` issue.

Comment: No prob @admdrew . Hopefully someone will give +1 because it works on HTTP traffic.

Comment: @admdrew ,   : I am trying ma best to solve this issue. Once i solved. I ll update if jpcap can capture http and how...

Comment: JpcapCaptor.dll where i can find that dll?